# nginx location directive does not return http status

Tags: nginx, configuration, ubuntu-20.04

*Note: I have read through the several Q/A's on SO, ServerFault, etc... but none of the answer seem to be working.*

Running an AWS ec2 Ubuntu (v20.04) web server with a basic nginx (v1.18) config. However, the `location` directive for `/a-custom-path` returning an http status code of 200 is never processed and/or is processed and ignored.

Here's the config:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;

    location /a-custom-path {
      access_log off;
      add_header Content-Type text/plain;
      return 200 'OK';
    }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/unknown.log;
    return 412;
}
```

The `location /a-custom-path` is never returning a 200 status; it always falls through to the 412 response. I've tried various location directives such as:

```
location /a-custom-path
location /a-custom-path/
location = /a-custom-path
location = /a-custom-path/
```

However, they all have the same behavior of falling through to the `412` response.

**Question** 
How can I create a custom location path that returns a 200 response and all other requests return a 412 response?

#### Edit - Revised & Working Config

For anyone else finding this question, here is the final working solution based on the accepted answer:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;

    # everything except '/a-custom-path' gets a 412 response
    location / {
      return 412;
    }

    location /a-custom-path {
      return 200 'OK';
      access_log off;
      add_header Content-Type text/plain;
    }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/unknown.log;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because things get nasty when you use `returns` not bound to any `location {}`.
Put your `return 412` inside `location / {}` and there will be happiness and joy.

P.S. When your web-server returns empty answer, you should use 204 status, not 200. Both will work, but 204 shows you know things.

Comment: Thanks. I'm from a Windows background and just assumed the `return` statement was a short-circuit and exited the config. Added a specific `location / { } ` block and all is well.